# Private variable with toString ()

Tags: java

Hi guys I'm creating a program that is a shoping cart and I'm trying to create a toString() method.

This is my GolfHat class

```
package ShoppingCart;

public class GolfHat extends Product {

    private String name;
    private String colour;
    private String make;
    private double price;

    public GolfHat(String type, String make, String name, String colour,double price) {

        this.type = "hat";
        name = name;
        colour = colour;
        make = make;
        price = price;

    }
```

and my product class is this

```
package ShoppingCart;

public class Product {

    public String type ;

    public  String toString (){
        if (type=="hat" ) {

            System.out.println ("Type: " + type + "\t" + "Make: " + make);
            return type;
        }

        if (type=="Glove"){

        }
            return "cant find";

    }
```

it wont let me use the make variable, I think it wont let me do this cause my variables are private however for part of my assesment i need to show a example of encaspulation and im struggerling to see where else I'll be able to do it

Comment: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions). The rest should be obvious.

Comment: @jlordo Nope, although string comparison is being made the wrong way, the code doesn't even compile because he is trying to access a private variable.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**First compilation error:**

```
System.out.println ("Type: " + type + "\t" + "Make: " + make);
```

`Product` doesn't have the `make` instance variable. Its subclass `GolfHat` declares the variable .  Subclass inherits non-private members of a superclass, it doesn't work the other way round.

**Logical error :**

```
if (type=="Glove"){

    }
```

This is an erroneous way of comparing String contents . Use `equals()` method instead.

```
if ("Glove".equals(type)){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a override `toString` method to your `golfHat`

```
public class GolfHat extends Product 
{
    public String toString ()
    {
        // you can use make here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Golfhat is a subclass of Product. Product knows nothing about make and shouldn't know. 
You can start reading from [inheritance tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)